# Laravel 4, Omit timestamps in Eloquent queries

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am working on an application and am using timestamps for administration and database purposes.

For my frontend api, I have created a series of json responses that return various objects and child objects, but on the frontend, I never make use of the timestamps.

Is there a way to omit timestamps from an Eloquent query without having to explicitly define all of the other columns with a `->select(['x', 'y'])` clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add a `$hidden` array property in your model and add those field names, for example:

```
class SomeModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $hidden = array('created_at', 'updated_at');

    // other code
}
```

Now those fields won't be in your `json/array` result.